# Maven deployment issues

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a maven project that is built using the archetype-site.

I left the default directory structure as it is and added a directory for my files, so my current structure is this:

```
MyProject
     -> src
     -> pages
     -> target
     -> pom.xml
```

The pages directory is the one I added and it has a variety of HTML/CSS/JS files.

I've defined a remote repository on my pom.xml and have added the credentials to the relevant section in the settings.xml file of maven.

I'm getting the following error which I do not understand when I'm trying to deploy. Googling also did not help.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project MyProject: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact MyProject:MyProject:jar:1.0-20121022.153807-1 in MyProject (https://bitbucket.org/MyApp/MyProject) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Is that all the error message you get? Any more output you could include? Also, running with `mvn -e` might give you a better error. Please include the actual command you used to deploy.

Comment: please attach `mvn -X` output, too.

Comment: You probably have some incorrect <distributionManagement> settings in pom.xml, please attach your pom.xml.